# Github remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/org/repo.git/' not found in Pycharm

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I am trying to push into a private repo in Github from Pycharm IDE but it constantly fails. I receive the following error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/org/repo.git' not found
```

I don't understand considering if I click the https link, it goes straight to my repo. I have also called `git remote -v` and in the list is the repo.

Why isn't this working?

Thanks

Comment: I think a private repository needs authentication, right? If so, does `git push` ask for username and password? If not, you may have specified a credential helper, which can be printed by `git config credential.helper`. You may have changed your password lately but the password stored in the helper hasn't got updated yet, and thus the old password is automatically used.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. When I try `git push` it asks me for my password and seems to be there. I'm now facing the issue posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811895/error-your-local-changes-to-the-following-files-would-be-overwritten-by-merge

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your network to some other provider, and give it a shot.

Or you can try running the command:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```