# Git/Github: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: README.md a_text_file.txt DONT EXIST

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I am trying to pull from a remote repo in Github to my folder. I want to be able to pull and push changes as I have them in my IDE.

Everytime I try and pull from the repo which I have set up as remote `origin` I get the following error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
 README.md a_text_file.txt
```

I don't understand this at all as this `a_text_file.txt` is not in my directory that is linked, nor is it in my repo, yet I cannot pull until this is resolved.

I have tried to unlink and relink the remote to the repo but still the error persists.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Are `README.md` and `a_text_file.txt` really on the _same line_ or is the formatting incorrect on your question and they merely _appear_ to be on the same line?  If they're on the same line, you have a single file named `README.md a_text_file.txt` which would answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to `checkout` some target, it will place the contents of the target on-disk.  If you have made changes on-disk, then `checkout` will (by default) refuse to overwrite any changes that you have made and will give you a checkout conflict:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    file_one
    file_two
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Note that each file that is in conflict is identified individually, one per line.

In *your* case, you have a conflict reported as:

```
README.md a_text_file.txt
```

In this case, this is not two files, but a single file.  Somehow you have ended up with a file named `README.md a_text_file.txt` in your working folder.  This happens to me periodically when I fat-finger a vi command or a shell redirection.  Or possibly when I write a script where whitespace is a delimiter, but only sometimes (like bash) and it ends up treating a list of paths as a single string instead of an array.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! The only problem is that if I try and search my computer I can't find the single file or either of the files separately. Would this mean it is randomly somewhere saved that I can't access?

Comment: No - it would be right in the root of your git working directory.  What does `ls -Flas README*` show?

Comment: It shows 'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I am on a windows system and using the terminal through Pycharm if this helps.

Comment: Interesting.  Could you run that in Git Bash?

Comment: $ ls -Flas README*
ls: cannot access 'README*': No such file or directory

Comment: Although I'm not in my Pycharm working directory if that makes any difference.